# The command in condition executes but then goes in the false block in (Delete 7 days older directories/files in UNIX)

Tags: bash, unix

I want to delete the old files.  But this code acts very weirdly. It considers the true condition as false

1. The line below in the IF condition executes, deletes the file.
2. But it doesn't print the ${message} in the mylogfile.log.
3. It jumps to the FALSE block.( I don't know why)
4. And on the shell screen it prints that  "No such file or directory"

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   timestamp=$(date +%F_%T)
   path="/blah/blah/blah/backupTest/"

   message="\n*********************************************** \n \t Successfully removed \n*********************************************** \n"

   if
        #--This line does delete the file but is considered as false 
        #--even if I remove the "&& ${message}" part
       find $path -name 'crm_backup_*' -type d -mtime +7 -print -exec rm -r {} \; && ${message} >> mylogfile.log
   then
        #--it never comes to this block
       echo "Finished at $timestamp" >> mylogfile.log
   else 
        #--It comes to this block
       echo "Removal failed at $timestamp" >> mylogfile.log
       exit 1
   fi
   ```

Comment: jmunsch, FYI, upon  bash -x ../scripts/removefile.sh, It gives error at this part;

../scripts/removefile.sh: line 10: \n***********************************************: command not found

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean `echo "${message}" >> "${logfile}"`, where the `echo` is missing in your code, so your command is the expansion of `$message` which means that the stars expand to the file names in the current directory, and the first file name is what it tries to execute, and that probably isn't what you intended, and because the message fails, the `if` fails, so it executes the `else` block?  (The `else` block will only be executed if both sides of the `&&` are successful — which means they both exit with a status of 0.)

```
if find $path -name 'crm_backup_*' -type d -mtime +7 -print -exec rm -r {} \; &&
   echo "${message}" >> mylogfile.log
then
    echo "Finished at $timestamp" >> mylogfile.log
else 
    echo "Removal failed at $timestamp" >> mylogfile.log
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan,
I did  
$ bash -x removefile.sh

And I got this one screen

++ date +%F_%T
+ timestamp=2014-12-18_18:44:11
+ path=/absolutepath/backupTest/
+ message='\n**** \n \t Successfully removed \n**** \n'
+ find /absolutepath/backupTest/ -name crm_backup_2014-12-18_16:23:48 -type d -mtime 0 -print -exec rm -r '{}' ';'
/absolutepath/backupTest/crm_backup_2014-12-18_16:23:48
find: `/absolutepath/backupTest/crm_backup_2014-12-18_16:23:48': No such file or directory
+ echo 'Finished at 2014-12-18_18:44:11'
+ exit 1
It deleted but OUTPUT in logfile=Removal failed at $timestamp only nothing else

Answer (score 0):

In path variable you are assigning the path from the root directory. If you didn't assign the path from the root directory it will take from the current directory. So make sure that path is from the root directory.

I checked that without the root directory that time only I get the error that is `No such file or directory`